# unordered_map<int, vector<float>> equivalent in Python

Tags: python, c++, hashmap

I need a structure in Python which maps an integer index to a vector of floating point numbers. My data is like:

```
[0] = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0}
[1] = {0.5, 1.0}
```

If I were to write this in C++ I would use the following code for define / add / access as follows:

```
std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<float>> VertexWeights;
VertexWeights[0].push_back(0.0f);
vertexWeights[0].push_back(1.0f);
vertexWeights[13].push_back(0.5f);
std::cout <<vertexWeights[0][0];
```

What is the equivalent structure of this in Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A **[dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)** of this format -> `{ (int) key : (list) value  }`

```
d = {}  # Initialize empty dictionary.
d[0] = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0] # Place key 0 in d, and map this array to it.
print d[0]
d[1] = [0.5, 1.0]
print d[1]
>>> [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
>>> [0.5, 1.0]
print d[0][0]  # std::cout <<vertexWeights[0][0];
>>> 1.0
```

Comment: in c++ if there isn't a key lets say d[15], then it is automatically created. But in Pyhton I get key error. Is there a way to overcome this ?

Comment: Yep, C++ and python work in the same way in this regard. Updated my answer. Python's dictionary literal is essentially an unordered map. @Cihan

Comment: @Cihan try [```collections.defaultdict(list)```](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

Answer (score 2):

How about dictionary and lists like this:

```
>>> d = {0: [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], 1: [0.5, 1.0]}
>>> d[0]
[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
>>> d[1]
[0.5, 1.0]
>>>
```

The key can be integers and associated values can be stored as a list. Dictionary in Python is a hash map and the complexity is amortized `O(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

In python we can this data structure as Dictionary.
Dictionaries are used to store data values in key:value pairs.
Example for Dictionary:
mydict = {
"brand": "Ford",
"model": "Mustang",
"year": 1964
}
we can also perform various operations like add, remove.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a `dict` with integers as keys and `list` as items, e.g.

```
m = dict()
m[0] = list()
m[0].append(1.0)
m[0].append(0.5)
m[13] = list()
m[13].append(13.0)
```

if it is not too much data

Comment: There should be `m[13] = list()` before `m[13].append(13.0)`.